# Write data as table structure in text file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am new to file system .I want to write data into text file in table structure(Rows & Columns). I found one module i.e., **easy-table** ,but its lack of wordwrap, table column headers are displaying zigzag manner.Any one can please help me to get this finish..Thank you.

Comment: hi try this npm [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table)

Comment: Hi vikash, thanks for early response. i have tried this module now, but no luck... I think this module useful for front end development

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, this will solve your problem, your table will be stored in tabledata.txt file when you run this script

```
const table = require('table').table;
const fs = require('fs');

let data = [
    ['0A', '0B', '0C'],
    ['1A', '1B', '1C'],
    ['2A', '2B', '2C']
];

let output = table(data);
console.log(output);

fs.writeFile("tabledata.txt", output,"utf8", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Here is the text file
[image: here is the text file]

Comment: hii tell me if it solved your problem, or if this is your usecase or not.

Comment: Hi, tried it, but file doesn't supporting this module content. please see below example , that the file is showing when i am using that module... 
  
  
  
  â•”â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•â•¤â•â•â•â•

Comment: it worked for me, are you able to see the console log ? check for encoding while writing the file

Comment: my node version is 8.0.0 please check your node version

Comment: the third option is encoding option take a look `fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback)` you can also try with writing simple string in a file and check node version as well. utf8 encoding will work for sure

Comment: HI, working if we use writeFile method.. but am using createWriteStream to write data into file... if i have 20 no.of columns, then table structure in getting disturbed.. columns are displaying overlapping others.... do you have any suggestion for this..

Comment: yes you can change your editor or notepad setting to view in perfect manner. just unselect text wrap property

Comment: My requirement is to open this file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to open the file in browser than you can generate html file with some css properties that will give you perfect format. You can try following code.

```
const table = require('table').table;
const fs = require('fs');

let data = [
    ['0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C'],
    ['0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C'],
    ['0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B','0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C', '0A', '0B', '0C']
];

let tableOutput = table(data);
console.log(tableOutput);

let fileData = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body style="white-space:pre; font-family:monospace">
${tableOutput}
</body>
</html>`;

fs.writeFile("tabledata.html", fileData, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

[image]

Comment: you can do that by deleting some css properties manually in browser but when you reload that it will again give you that unformated result and there is no proper solution as by default the browser set some css properties to text file.